# Best way to deal with many small pictures

Tags: graphics, floats, thesis, layout

I have a document which looks like this

[image]

As you probably noticed I have lots of small pictures and because I have a one-column layout (I want to keep using it, at least as default for the whole document) these images take up a lot of space and there is little space for text. What is a good way to deal with this?

I don't know if this makes a difference but this is part of a Master's thesis.

Comment: Please avoid including "all the packages that you use" and build a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) instead.

Comment: @Miyase I decided to remove the packages, I think it is not important since I'm willing to change how I make my pictures.

Comment: this is really off topic here, sorry. You can ask how to implement a layout in Tex but asking what design to use is a design question not a tex one. You could obviously merge 9 and 10 having 4 in  row and making some adjusted caption but it is for you to decide if that improves your document, we can not help

Comment: any code you post should be useful to show the problem and test answers, a fragment using an unsupplied image does neither. you could make a complete document using `\rule{3cm}{3cm}` (or whatever size you need) as the images (but it really is off topic)

Comment: There is also the wrapfig approach, but that works best for relatively narrow images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one (1) float `figure` but with *n* (2,3 ...) `minipage`s, each with a width set  to some less than 1/2, 1/3 ... of the `\linewidth` of the text, an image (always with width=`\linewidth`, i.e., all the width of the minipage) plus a standard `\caption` inside. And use `\hfill` between minipages to add some margin between. That is:

---

[image: Mwe1]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}  
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{\lipsum[2][1-2]}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}  
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{\lipsum[2][1-2]}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]  
\end{document}
```

Or alternatively, use *n* columns using the  `multicol` package inside the float to simplify the code. Example for three small figures:

---

[image: mwe]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{multicols}{3}    
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{\lipsum[1][1-3]}\newcolumn
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{\lipsum[2][1-2]}\newcolumn
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{\lipsum[3][1-3]}
\end{multicols}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!